# Are all conserved scalars proportional to relativistic mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, velocity, relativity

I have read in Rindler's relativity book that all scalars depend only on the magnitude of velocity of a particle and that are *conserved* are proportional to relativistic mass.
$$m(\vec{v})=m_{0}/\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}$$
How it can be proven?

Apparently, a similar argument is true for relativistic momentum; how it can be shown if it is true?

Comment: I think thinking in terms of relativistic mass is probably the *wrong* way to start.

Comment: @KyleKanos assume relativistic mass is just a definition as above

Comment: That doesn't change my statement, starting with a bunk idea such as relativistic mass will lead to misunderstanding because the foundation is bunk.

Comment: @KyleKanos what is misunderstood here? I think my question is clear and it doesn't related to "mass" concept. My question is almost a mathematics question

Comment: I didn't say anything was misunderstood, I said that using the notion of relativistic mass would lead to misunderstanding. There are plenty of resources on this site about the dangers of that concept.

Comment: @KyleKanos yes you are right. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Is it me, or is the so-called relativistic mass *not* Lorentz *invariant* at all? This would not make any sense; recall, it's the 0-component of a Lorentz 4-vector.

Comment: @Danu Indeed it's not. K. N. O., I tried to fix up your question to make the wording more clear, but I'm not sure if I got it right. If the edited question doesn't reflect what you meant to ask, you can change the wording as needed, or comment here and we can help suggest a better wording.

Comment: The question makes sense only with "relativistic mass" -> "rest mass."

Comment: But the most common Lorentz invariants (mass, speed of light in a vacuum, etc.) don't include the gamma factor. Honestly, I can't even make sense of this question.

Comment: Rindler is a pretty wacky book... we technically use it for relativity at my university, but nobody likes it. It's super confusing and archaic; you'd be better off with almost anything else.

Comment: @DavidZ I have changed the question. It should not to be Lorentz-invariant, it should be conserved.

Comment: @knzhou yes, it is really confusing

Comment: Which Rindler book? [Relativity: Special, General, and Cosmological](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Relativity-Special-Cosmological-Wolfgang-Rindler/dp/0198567324) or [Introduction To Special Relativity](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Special-Relativity-Science-Publications/dp/0198539525), or some other book? In what chapter/section/page does the statement appear?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It is really clear what I asked. Please indicate the ambiguous point

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what the book pretends to show, the theory identified by the existence of $X^{\mu}(\tau)$ in an Lorentz-Poincaré symmetric spacetime can construct physical scalars only by some functionality of $\dot{X}^{\mu}\dot{X}_{\mu}$. The $\dot{}=d/d\tau$ came from the translations in space-time and the product $A_{\mu}B^{\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu}B^{\nu}$, where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric, came from the Lorentz transformations.

Then, going to some coordinate system and put things dependent on $X^{0}$ we have:
$$
\sqrt{\dot{X}^{\mu}\dot{X}_{\mu}}=\frac{dX^{0}}{d\tau}\sqrt{-1+
\frac{dX^{j}}{dX^{0}}\frac{dX_{j}}{dX^{0}}}=-\frac{E}{m_0}\sqrt{1-v^2}
$$
this square root are also a scalar in the Lorentz-Poincaré transformations with $X_0$ fixed (boost are no more allowed). If we want some quantity that is independent of time $X_0$ we may pick the energy $E$ of this referential frame and then make all the others conserved "scalar" quantities dependent on energy.

You can see then that any scalar in the space-like $3d$ volume need to be proportinal $m(\vec{v})=m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2}$, but this is clearly not a scalar in $4d$ spacetime

Answer (score 0):

Per Danu's comment, if $m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ were Lorentz invariant, it would follow (because $m_0$ is Lorentz invariant) that $v$ is Lorentz invariant.  So neither relativistic mass nor anything proportional to it can be Lorentz invariant.

Of course the notion, elsewhere in the comments, that it's somehow not possible to talk meaningfully about the expression $m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ in the first place, is proven wrong by the fact that we just talked meaningfully about it.

**Edited to add:**  Now that the question is edited (and completely changed by the edit), my first paragraph is no longer relevant.  Thanks to K.N.O. for alerting me to this.

**Edited to add further:** Regarding the current version of the question --- any constant scalar depends only on velocity (vacuously) and is conserved, but is not proportional to relativistic mass (for a particle with non-zero mass in the first place).

Comment: No, that is not at *all* what I said.

Comment: Check the question again

Comment: You are right but I guess he has assumed any non-trivial scalar (any non-constant scalar) is proportional to m.

Answer (score 0):

Relativistic mass is indeed the time component of the 4-momentum, and that is exactly why is it NOT invariant.

Comment: Check the question again